# Why does webpack import dead javascript code?

Tags: javascript, webpack, tree-shaking

My webpack config has `DefinePlugin` definition:

```
module.exports = env => {
    const PROD = env.production;
    const mode = env.mode || (PROD ? 'production' : 'development');

    const plugins = [
        new LicenseCheckerWebpackPlugin(...),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(...),
        new webpack.BannerPlugin(...),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin(...),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(...),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin(...),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            DEBUG: JSON.stringify(!PROD),
        }),
        new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(...),
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new ESLintPlugin(...),
    ];

    return {
        mode,
        performance: {...},
        entry: {...},
        output: {...},
        optimization: {
            minimize: mode === 'production',
            minimizer: [
                new TerserPlugin({
                    terserOptions: {
                        compress: {
                            drop_console: true,
                        },
                        output: {
                            ascii_only: true,
                        },
                    },
                }),
                new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
            ],
        },
        stats: 'minimal',
        watchOptions: { aggregateTimeout: 200 },
        devtool: mode === 'production' ? false : 'inline-source-map',
        resolve: {...},
        module: {
            rules: [...],
        },
        plugins,
    };
};
```

JS code:

```
import { MyDebugModule } from './my-debug-module';

if (DEBUG) {
    MyDebugModule();
}
```

There is no a call of `MyDebugModule()` in the final bundle, but webpack imports the code from `my-debug-module.js` when `DEBUG` is `false`.
If I completely remove the code `if (DEBUG) { MyDebugModule(); }` webpack removes the `my-debug-module` code.

```
webpack@5.88.2
```

`sideEffects` does not affect to the imported module.
Upd. Actually, it was wrong in my case.

Comment: The [documentation](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#defineplugin) states "*the values will be inlined into the code which **allows a minification pass** to remove the redundant conditional*" - it does not remove the `if` statement by itself. Do you actually have that minifiction pass in your config? And does it occur before tree shaking?

Comment: @Bergi yes, I can confirm that the final bundle does not contain that `if` condition, but still have an imported module code

Comment: I disabled `optimization` but still see the same result

Comment: Then probably the order of the plugins is wrong - the call needs to be removed before the bundling happens. Can you share a complete webpack config (that is necessary to reproduce the issue)?

Comment: @Bergi I've added more details of a webpack config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sideEffects` affected to the imported module - that's why webpack leaves it in the code. It has an expression that matches with `my-debug-module.js`

Comment: What do you mean by "affected" here?

Comment: @TylerH It has an expression that matches with `my-debug-module.js`